# How to get live views count on livestreaming in laravel 9?

Tags: live-streaming

I am using **co-streamer** as a streaming server, also **plyr** as a video player.
In my mind one approach is to get number of views in a specific method and call in ajax with setTimeInterval method.

But there might be some best way or package to do it?

Any good suggestion about approach or package about views count just like youtube?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 approaches.

Either you can use socket communication and send back number of live user. You will need some kine of identifier i.e Principal Id if talking in terms of Spring In java

Or as you mentioned use some kind of polling to get counts